# About union in C

Tags: c, union-types

```
union a
{
    int i;
    char ch[4];
};
void main()
{
    union a u;
    u.ch[0]=3;
    u.ch[1]=2;
    u.ch[2]=0;
    u.ch[3]=0;
    printf("%d %d %d",u.ch[0],u.ch[1], u.i);
}
```

Ouput : 3 2 515

Why i get 515 for u.i Can anyone please explain me about this?

Comment: Because 3200 is not the same as [3][2][0][0], 3200 needs two bytes to be represented [0x0c][0x80].

Comment: I'm not getting..

Comment: Try `printf("%x %x %x",u.ch[0],u.ch[1], u.i);` to gain insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this,
the system will allocate 2 bytes for the union. The statements `u.ch[0]=3,u.ch[1]=2`store data in memory as given below.

[image]

To be more clear

```
u.ch[0]=3;
u.ch[1]=2;
```

Now u.i is calculated as

```
(2)(3) in binary form which is equal to 515.

(2) --> 00000010; (3) --> 00000011

(2)(3) --> 0000001000000011 --> 515.
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please correct the answer for the benefit of others as well. Thanks.

Comment: is this same for struct??

Comment: Union uses Shared memory which is not the case with structure. So, char[] and int i occupy the same memory location here. So I think it is not the same while using structure.

Comment: Artwork alone is worth the UV.  Easier than explaining `(2 << 8) | 3`. @JagadeshJai - no it is not the same for a `struct`. Within a `struct` each member has its own memory provided. In a `union` there is only storage for either one or the other members, but not both.

Answer (score 3):

The result you're getting is 2*256 + 3, or 0x00000203. This is system dependent behavior, different systems have different byte orders (and officially, you're not guaranteed to get a valid value at all for u.i, though implementations where you don't are rare). This is because your system is little-endian, so bytes are in the "reverse" order from how you would read a number from left to right.

The most common alternative result is that on big-endian systems, the result will be 0x03020000, or 50462720. On a 16-bit big-endian system, it might be 770; on one where int is 64 bits [most 64-bit systems are not], it may be 216735732067205120, though I'm not sure if the last four bytes are guaranteed to be zeroed out when your array member only has four entries.

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: wow super thank you so much... I got more information from your explanation.